# EE control panel dashboard search field

Tags: control-panel, search

the search field in EE's dashboard doesn't seem to find anything. what is this field supposed to search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It searches for (some) settings in the control panel. So you could search for *file*, and you should get a result/link to the file manager. Similarly, searches for *category*, *channel*, *username* should all return results with links to the respective areas of the CP.

However, the search results aren't consistent. Search for *security* and you don't get any results, yet a search for *session* gives a result for the *Security and Session Preferences*.

I'd say its there for someone who has limited knowledge of EE general options and wants to access some of the preferences, but can't find them.

Not entirely useful though!

Comment: thanks. I guess that makes it fairly useless. I've never quite noticed it in 7 years of working with EE but now my client (with limited knowledge) is asking me about it and I had to scratch my head.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [Switchboard](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchboard) as I guess it will give you more of the functions and results you'd expect from a search in the CP.